# Change node name of xml serializer

Tags: symfony, xml-serialization

i'm trying to generate a sitemap in Symfony using a ArrayCollection and the symfony Serializer. My code is:

```
$result = new ArrayCollection();

$result->add(array(
    "loc" => "http://example.com",
    "priority" => 1
));

$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder("urlset"));
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), $encoders);

$xmlContent = $serializer->serialize($items,'xml');

return $xmlContent;
```

It works pretty well, except that the nodes have the wrong name. The resulting xml looks something like:

```
<urlset>
    <item key="0">
        <loc>http://example.com</loc>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </item>
</urlset>
```

What i want to do is change the item *node* to *url*. Is there a way i  can achieve this using the Symfony serializer?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know if this is doable with the symfony xml serializer. In the end i used https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found is to copy the XmlEncoder into a CustomXmlEncoder and to replace the 'item' label (2 occurrences) by a key in the context.
Not very clean but it is the only way to make it dynamic.